# Is it necessary to use @Embedded for Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have models with nested entity inside them. Is it necessary to write annotation @Embedded and @Embedeable or it's not necessary in actual Spring version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you still need to use these in Spring, since these are JPA annotations and are necessary when you are embedding a given type within another entity.